# MVC WebDeploy Includes Referenced Assembly Xml Documentation Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webdeploy

I'm using WebDeploy to package my ASP .Net MVC3 project for deployment, but I'm finding that the package is being bloated by a number of xml files. These appear to be XML documentation, presumably used by VS2010 for intellisense.

For example, in my built package (and build dir) I have both NHibernate.dll and NHibernate.xml.

- Do these xml doc files need to be deployed?
- How can I exclude them from the build / webdeploy if not?

Thanks!

Comment: I just asked a similar question - sorry, didn't find yours. Did you find anything? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842519/skip-xml-documentation-files-with-web-deploy/9844967

Answer (score 2):

Two 
things to check:

1) Are you using a debug build instead of a release build to build your package?

2) For information on excluding specific files or folders from a deployment, see the [ASP.NET Web Application Project Deployment FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx). There's also a blog post on [customizing a deployment package](http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html) that has information on how to use skip rules to exclude files or folders from a particular Web Deploy operation.