# Skip XML documentation files with Web Deploy

Tags: .net, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, xml-documentation

I'm trying to publish a .NET web service using Web Deploy. Currently it's including XML documentation files in the package. I've unchecked "XML documentation file" in the Build tab of the project properties in Visual Studio. This stops that XML file from being published, but the project references a number of custom libraries that have XML documentation.

Obviously we don't want to turn off documentation for our custom libraries. There's also no reason to deploy these XML files.

From either the msdeploy/msbuild command line or from the project properties, how can I prevent XML documentation files from being included in the package and the subsequent web deployment?

**Update**

I've tried adding `DEL /Q "$(TargetDir)*.xml"` to the Pre- and Post-build events without success. The XML files are still added to the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will globally disable generation of XML documentation:

```
msbuild some.web.sln /p:DocumentationFile=""
```

To skip *.xml files with MSDeploy.exe:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath=c:\sourcedir -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*.xml -dest:contentPath=c:\newdir
```

Comment: That works for that project, but I can do that in the project properties. The problem is the (binary) referenced libraries that have XML documentation.

Comment: I see. Added msdeploy example of skipping all xml files. You can append `-whatif` flag to the command the get a preview.